# django link to a specific admin view

Tags: python, django, templates, model-view-controller, django-admin

Let's say I have this url: `localhost/admin/app_name/model_name/`. How can I link to this inside my template?

I have already linked the admin page like so

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
```

Is there a variant of this I should use?

I'm using 1.5.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse admin list page url as follow:

```
{% url 'admin:app_model_changelist' %}
```

For other admin pages, see [Reversing admin URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) from Django documentation.

Comment: you mean `app_name_model_name_changelist` dont you ?

Comment: @FoxMaSk, Yes, you are right. I avoided `app_name` and `model_name` because it could confuse the reader.

Comment: @falsetry : ok , that was to be sharped for the OP's request ;)

Comment: @FoxMaSk, What is `sharped`? Does it have same meaning with `sharpened`? (I'm not good at English, I couldn't find `sharp` with appropriate meaning in my English-Korean dictionary).

Comment: I meant "accurate"; that was sharp I meant not sharped